# how to export a manually graph from mathematica

Tags: graphics, export

I draw [`Cos`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cos.html) function using the code line :

```
GraphicsColumn[
  {
   Plot[Cos[0.0625*Pi x], {x, 0, 40*Pi}, Axes -> False], 
   Plot[Cos[0.0625*Pi x], {x, 0, 40*Pi}, Axes -> False], 
   Plot[Cos[0.0625*Pi x], {x, 0, 40*Pi}, Axes -> False], 
   Plot[Cos[0.0625*Pi x], {x, 0, 40*Pi}, Axes -> False]
  }
  ,ImageSize -> Large
]
```

and manually add circles and arrows as you can see in the attached picture , how can I export the figure . export doesn't work and I can't save it or copy it please help
[image: see image]

Comment: I don't know how to edit from Word, but if I add arrows to a sine plot using the drawing tools and then export _the graphic_, it seems to work fine. See [here](https://imgur.com/woB7QZ4)

Answer (score 2):

I know this post could be shorter, but I wanted to outline a methodology, as in teach a man to fish..., so please bear with me. The first point to make is that the geometric scale of x vs y is easiest to manage from within the Graphics[] environment. Each Plot[] command creates its own coordinate context and so you can introduce distortions you don't intend unless you apply a great deal of care. Secondly, mixing different graphical elements is easiest to do in Graphics[] as well.

First of all, decide how to draw the 4 cosine curves. I noticed that your diagrams simply have 4 cycles and no axes so I dispensed with the frequency and duration you used. Here we have a quick set of 4 cosines in a column:

```
With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01]},
    Module[{s},
        s = Cos[2 Pi t];
        Graphics[{
            Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}]
        }]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Notice I separated the curves by a little more than their peak to peak height.

Now we want to draw the dots in a systematic way. Imagine each set of dots is drawn with respect to a point on the baseline associated with the cosine curve. We can use the baseline index to also choose that time position.

```
With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01], tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5}},
    Module[{s, dots},
        s = Cos[2 \[Pi] t];
        dots[k_] := With[{td = tdots[[k]], y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, r = 0.16},
            {Red, Disk[{td, y0 + dy}, r], Disk[{td, y0}, r], Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}
        ];
        Graphics[{
            Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}],
            Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}]
        }]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Now let's add the arrows. We will call them hop's. Here we will also assign the output to the variable g for export below.

```
g = With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01], 
    tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5}},
    Module[{s, dots, hop},
        s = Cos[2 \[Pi] t];
        dots[k_] := 
        With[{td = tdots[[k]], y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, r = 0.16},
            {Red, Disk[{td, y0 + dy}, r], Disk[{td, y0}, r], Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}
        ];
        hop[k1_, k2_] := With[{y = baseline[[k1]] + 1, t1 = tdots[[k1]], t2 = tdots[[k2]]},
        Arrow[BezierCurve[
            {{t1, y}, {0.9 t1 + 0.1 t2, y + 0.5}, {0.1 t1 + 0.9 t2, y + 0.5}, {t2, y}}]
        ] ];
        Graphics[{
            Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}],
            Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}],
            hop[1, 2], hop[2, 3], hop[3, 4], hop[4, 1]
        }]
    ]
]
```

[image]

You want to export to a pixel oriented format like png as opposed to a photographic image format like jpg because the jpg image compression can introduce artifacts. This command will save the png file in the same directory as the notebook containing this code.

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "dot_hops.png"}],g,ImageResolution->200]
```

Comment: I appreciate that a lot thank you very much I am a beginner user of mathematica  your explaination helps alot

Comment: Your thanks are my reward, but would you mind accepting my answer?

Comment: how I can change your code so instead of 3 balls in one site ,I would have  2 balls in site and 1 ball in the next neighbor site ? I would appreciate so much if you can answer me , thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can adapt this then `Export` works just fine

```
g1 = GraphicsColumn[{
  Plot[Cos[0.0625*Pi x], {x, 0, 40*Pi}, Axes -> False, 
   Epilog -> {Disk[{5 Pi, 3/4}, {8, .2}], Disk[{5 Pi, 1/4}, {8, .2}],
   Arrowheads[{-.05, .05}], 
   Arrow[BezierCurve[{{5 Pi, 1.1}, {10 Pi, 1.3}, {15 Pi, 1.1}}]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1.5}], 
  Plot[Cos[0.0625*Pi x], {x, 0, 40*Pi}, Axes -> False, 
   Epilog -> {Disk[{10 Pi, 3/4}, {8, .2}], Disk[{10 Pi, 1/4}, {8, .2}]
  }]}, ImageSize -> Large]
Export["g1.jpg", g1]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks ! but how can I add the arrow ?

Comment: Exactly how did you add the arrow to your plot? Perhaps you can do the same thing, but I cannot know without seeing what you did.

Comment: I copy the curved arrow from word to mathematica

Comment: Option 1: Use software like Adobe to combine exported graphics from Mathematica with exported graphics from Word.  Option 2: Learn how to fiddle with the unending details of creating graphics inside Mathematica to generate the arrows that look the way you want them to. See above for a very simple example of this. Option 3: Generate all the graphics inside Adobe or inside PostScript.

Comment: Or, option 4, use the Drawing Tools (or other software?)  to modify the graphic within Mathematica and then export the _modified graphic_  (+1)